# MYSQL, ON DUPLICATE UPDATE and IF

Tags: mysql, if-statement, insert, duplicates

My query look actually to :

```
INSERT INTO `table` (f1,f2,status) VALUES 
(1,5,'on'),  (3,2,'on'), (15,20,'on') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status='off';
```

But how to add IF status="on" then do this update ? I tried

```
INSERT INTO `table` (f1,f2,status) VALUES 
(1,5,'on'),  (3,2,'pending'), (15,20,'on') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status='off' IF(status='pending');
```

But seems doesn't work, I didn't understand well this part in documentation.

Any help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good documentation and example demonstrating the same [MySQL IF Function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-function.aspx).

Syntax of the MySQL IF function is as follows:
 **IF(expr, if_true_expr, if_false_expr)**

If the `expr` evaluates to `TRUE`, the IF function returns the `if_true_expr`, otherwise it returns `if_false_expr`.

Now, coming to your question, assuming you want to update the status with `'on'` or `'off'` or `'pending'` or user input for column `status` based on status value as on , the query should be like below:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (f1,f2,status) VALUES 
    (1,5,'on'),  (3,2,'pending'), (15,20,'on') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status = IF(VALUES(status) = 'on', VALUES(status), 'off');
```